# Best WebGIS framework for WMS

Tags: java, asp.net, frameworks, gis, wms

I need to make a demo web project with extensive support for reading and editing WM(T)S, like [this project](http://czerwonak.igeoplan.pl/). For technology Java or .NET are possible solutions. I tired [GeoMajas](http://www.geomajas.org/) for couple of days now, but it get annoying error about refresh of main map that I can't solve. Also, community support is non-existing as there are only mialing lists about development of GeoMajas, no forum to help solve this problem. Any advice on what framework to choose?

Comment: Have you tried posting your question on the development mailing list? They normally try to help you there.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking at one of the following

- Openlayers http://openlayers.org/
- Leaflet http://leafletjs.com/
- Geo Ext http://opengeo.org/technology/geoext/

These are all java script libraries so if you really need to you can inlcude them in a Java or .net based website.

If your looking for a more complete framework I would look at the OpenGeo suite. If you download it and look at the Geoexplorer app makes a good starting point and it uses the OpenGeo GSP Libries which are basically a warpper around GeoExt and Openlayers.